# Deriving density of states in different dimensions in k space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, geometry, density-of-states

The results for deriving the density of states in different dimensions is as follows:

- 3D: $g(k)dk = 1/(2\pi)^3 4 \pi k^2 dk$
- 2D: $g(k)dk = 1/(2\pi)^2 2 \pi k dk$
- 1D: $g(k)dk = 1/(2\pi) 2 dk$

I get for the 3d one the $4\pi k^2 dk$ is the volume of a sphere between $k$ and $k + dk$. Similarly for 2D we have $2\pi kdk$ for the area of a sphere between $k$ and $k + dk$. However I am unsure why for 1D it is $2dk$ as opposed to $2 \pi dk$. So could someone explain to me why the factor is $2dk$?

Answer (score 1):

The factor of pi comes in because in 2 and 3 dim you are looking at a thin circular or spherical shell in that dimension, and counting states in that shell.  In 1-dim there is no real "hyper-sphere" or to be more precise the logical extension to 1-dim is the set of disjoint intervals, {-dk, dk}.  Pardon my notation, this represents an interval dk symmetrically placed on each side of k = 0 in k-space.  Hence the differential hyper-volume in 1-dim is 2*dk.  The factor of 2 because you must count all states with same energy (or magnitude of k).  In 2-dim the shell of constant E is 2*pi*k*dk, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of an $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $k$, also called an "[n-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball)", is

$$
V_n(k) = \frac{\pi^{n/2} k^n}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}
$$

The volume of an infinitesimal spherical shell of thickness $dk$ is

$$
S_n(k) dk = \frac{d V_{n} (k)}{dk} dk = \frac{n \ \pi^{n/2} k^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)} dk
$$

where $S_n$ is the surface area.

For example, for $n=3$ we have the usual 3D sphere. Its volume is

$$
V_3(k) = \frac{\pi^{3/2} k^3}{\Gamma(3/2+1)} = \frac{\pi \sqrt \pi}{\frac{3 \sqrt \pi}{4}} k^3 = \frac 4 3 \pi k^3
$$

The surface area is

$$
S_3(k) = \frac {d}{dk}  \left( \frac 4 3 \pi k^3 \right) = 4 \pi k^2
$$

and the thickness of the infinitesimal shell is

$$
S_3(k) dk = 4 \pi k^2 dk
$$

In 1D, the "sphere" of radius $k$ is a *segment* of length $2k$ (why? think about the [general definition of a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), or more precisely a ball...). The above equations give you

$$
V_1(k) = 2k\\
S_1(k) = 2\\
S_1(k) dk = 2dk\\
$$